# Очередной Конфликт Функций (Счетчик внутри счетчика)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция которая считает удары по монстру

```
Let hp = 10;
 function hit(){
                if (hp >=0) {
                hp = hp - 1 ;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hp;       
                 }checkWin();}
```

Мне в определенный момент нужно сменить изображение в `div`. Я это делаю так

```js
function checkWin() {
  if (hp <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('hp').textContent = 'You won!';
    hp = 500;
    counter = counter + 1 ;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
  }
  if (counter===4 ) {
    r1();  // Меняем картинку
  }
}
```

Функция `r1` реализована так

```js
function r1() {
  const div1 = document.querySelector('.monster1');
  div1.className = 'monster2'; 
}
```

Но вот беда, когда функция checkWin() доходит до значения (counter===4 ) она действительно меняет значения монстра, а при следующем ударе (выполняя `hit()`) Консоль выдает Красноту Такого содержания

> Ударь по врагу еще раз0.45b — копия.html:293 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
> at r1 (Ударь по врагу еще раз0.45b — копия.html:293)
> at checkWin (Ударь по врагу еще раз0.45b — копия.html:261)
> at magick (Ударь по врагу еще раз0.45b — копия.html:288)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Ударь по врагу еще раз0.45b — копия.html:232)

На строке 293 у меня стоит та самая функция `r1` по смене монстра.

И прекрасно понимаю, почему браузер ругается - 'className' теперь другой, Ведь Я Поменял Его Через DOM!

Я наплодил данную матрешку (Функция Внутри Функции Внутри Функции) и теперь не знаю как сменить монстра корректно. Я думал уже о том, чтобы удалить функцию r1() после первого ее выполнения, через тот же DOM. Но может есть более корректные способы ?

В идеале условие должно выглядеть не - "выполнять каждый раз когда счётчик будет равен 4 (counter===4 )", а - "как только счётчик будет равен 4 выполнить функцию r1() один раз". Только как это сказать программе я не знаю..((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вам придется переписать код. Даже если решите проблему вызова функции, код изначально проблемный, т.к. рассчитан на двух монстров. Если их будет 15, у каждого - разные hp, окажется, что надо было для каждого монстра сделать свой объект с данными: ХП, урон, картинка и прочее.

Какой-то вариант на коленке (слова `class, constructor` пугают новичков, поэтому здесь они не использованы):

```js
let kill_count = 0;

/***/
let monster_list = [
  { hp: 10, img: "https://gyazo.com/c9745975724e9e0f87c4cebe6462205e.png" },
  { hp: 20, img: "https://gyazo.com/710ce28f75e8a098fdf091e92bc482ba.png" },
];

let monster_hp = null;

let monster_elem = document.querySelector(".monster");
// Это решение вашей проблемы: Изначально сохранить ссылку на элемент
// в переменной, независимо от класса.

let monster_index = -1;

function monster_curr() {
  // возвращает объект текущего монстра.
  return monster_list[monster_index];
}

function monster_next() {
  monster_index++;  
  let monster = monster_curr();
  
  if (!monster) {
    alert("Вы всех убили!");
    document.body.textContent = "You Win";
  }
  
  monster_hp = monster.hp;
  monster_elem.style.backgroundImage = `url('${ monster.img }')`;
}


function monster_display_dmg(num) {
  // Для всплывающего урона. Не удержался =)
  
  num = Math.round(num);
  
  let dmg = document.createElement("div");
  dmg.className = "dmg";
  dmg.textContent = num;
  
  dmg.style.top = 80 + Math.random() * 25 + "px";
  dmg.style.left = 75 + Math.random() * 50 + "px";
  
  monster_elem.appendChild(dmg);
  
  setTimeout(function() {    
    dmg.style.transform = "translateY(-50px)";
    dmg.style.opacity = 0;
  }, 50);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    monster_elem.removeChild(dmg);
  }, 500);
}

/***/
monster_next();
let player_strength = 2;

document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (monster_hp >= 0) {
    monster_hp -= player_strength;
    monster_display_dmg(-player_strength);
    
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = monster_hp;
  }
  
  check_win();
});

function check_win() {
  if (monster_hp > 0) return;
  
  kill_count++;
  monster_hp = monster_curr().hp * (kill_count % 4);
  
  document.getElementById('hp').textContent = 'You won!';
  document.getElementById("counter").textContent = kill_count;
  
  if (kill_count > 0 && kill_count % 4 == 0) {
    monster_next();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.monster {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dmg {
  position: absolute;
  
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
    1px 1px #000,
    1px -1px #000,
    -1px 1px #000,
    -1px -1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="monster"></div>

<div>
  <button id="hit">Удар!</button>

  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id="hp"></div>
  <div>Убито: <span id="counter">0</span></div>
</div>
```

Здесь тоже есть проблема: Переключение через каждые 4 монстра. Это число тоже может меняться? Тогда можно было бы его тоже хранить в объекте монстра: Сколько таких же надо убить, чтобы вызывалось переключение на следующего. После каждого убитого уменьшать на 1, дойдет до нуля - переключить.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Прикольные монстры получились. )))

Answer (score 3):

Используйте другой способ поиска целевого объекта. Например так

```js
function r1() {
  const div1 = document.getElementById('monster');
  div1.className = 'monster2'; 
}
```

Или так

```js
function r1() {
  const div1 = document.querySelector('.monster');
  div1.classList.remove('monster1'); 
  div1.classList.add('monster2'); 
}
```

А чтобы выполнить функцию ровно один раз достаточно не обнулять переменную `counter`

Comment: Спасибо большое